# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" (I entered digits, but it seems to have read an empty string)

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

There is something wrong in this section:

```java
BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String faaltu = cin.readLine();
String inp = cin.readLine();
String[] part = inp.split("\\s");

for(int k = 0; k < part.length; k++)
{
    System.out.println(part[k]);
}

obj.Smax = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
```

I gave the following input:

```
2
4 12345
3 1234
```

Here is the complete code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codejam
{
    Codejam(){};
    static Codejam obj = new Codejam();
    int totalStanding = 0;
    int T;//no of test cases
    int[] S;// no of people at each given shyness level
    boolean[] standing;
    int Smax;
    int total = 0, newInv = 0;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        obj.T = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());
        for(int i = 0; i < obj.T; i++)
        {
            obj.populate();
            obj.update();
            while (obj.totalStanding < obj.total)
            {
                obj.newInv++;
                obj.S[0]++;
                obj.update();
            }
            System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + obj.newInv);
        }


    }

    public void update()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < obj.S.length; i++)
        {
            if ((totalStanding >= i) && (obj.standing[i] == false) )
            {
                obj.totalStanding += obj.S[i];
                obj.standing[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    public void populate() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String faaltu = cin.readLine();
        String inp = cin.readLine();
        String[] part = inp.split("\\s");

        for(int k = 0; k < part.length; k++)
        {
            System.out.println(part[k]);
        }

        obj.Smax = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
        obj.S = new int[Smax + 1]; 
        obj.standing = new boolean[Smax + 1];
        for(int j = 0;j < part[1].length(); j++)
        {
            obj.S[j] = part[1].charAt(j) - '0';
            obj.total += S[j];

        }

    }

}
```

and got exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
>       For input string: "" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) 
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at Codejam.populate(Codejam.java:57)
>       at Codejam.main(Codejam.java:24)

Please point out where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to read too many lines from your input.

I suspect you are reading past the end of file.

I suggest you pass `cin.readline ()` to your `populate()` method as an argument so you don't have to open another reader.

You also shouldn't have to escape your split expression so heavily I think it currently reads "a backslash and an s" rather than "whitespace".

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Thanks :)
About the escape character:  If you are using an escaped construct within a string literal, you must precede the backslash with another backslash for the string to compile. (taken from [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) )

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear, you tried to parse to a number an empty string which thrown an exception.

We have no idea what is your input, but `part[0]` is the empty string causing the error :

```
obj.Smax = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
```

Comment: i gave the input:
2
4 12345
3 1234

Comment: @gnsb If really that was the input received, your split would work. Please print `inp` just before parsing it and tell me the output.

Comment: printing variables to test the program made me realize the mistake: i had read past the end of file
Thanks a lot for the help :)